# Starting with noflo and flowhub

Tags: node.js, noflo

I recently started working with noflow and flowhub. The basic concept of using noflo seems quiet easy to understand. However, when I started running flowhub from my machine and setting up the nodejs environement it gets quiet heavy. First of all I havent found any detailed documentation yet. I started with this one:
https://docs.flowhub.io/getting-started-node/

When I execute this command:
   `node node_modules/.bin/noflo-nodejs-init --user <YOUR USER ID> --host    localhost --port 3569 --label "Local NoFlo Test`"
 in my CMD i get this message:

```
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
```

of course I replaced  by my Github-ID and nodejs is installed. However, I dont know what

> --label

means exactly. Somehow even the --help wont work so I think it is a setup problem not mentined in the documentation. Do i have to define some environment variables? Like it seems to be a problem with the dirname or in basedir? But I dont know which directory to put in here.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Since Im using windows (perhaps) I managed to solve this error by changing the command to

> .\node_modules.bin\noflo-nodejs-init --user  --host
>   localhost --port 3569 --label "Local NoFlo Test"

Whats perhaps helpful for you is to remove the brackets when putting in YOUR USER ID.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't *< your user id >* supposed to be your user id on flowhub...?

e.g. `.\node_modules.bin\noflo-nodejs-init --user BoatyMcBoatFace --host localhost --port 3569 --label "Local NoFlo Test"`

see https://github.com/noflo/noflo-nodejs, the piece on persistent runtime config.

As I read it when you're running the `.\node_modules.bin\noflo-nodejs` command you can specify config in the `flowhub.json` file, and if you need override, pass parameters on the command line.